# Set a JLabel to a percentage of the window

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, dimensions

I have a `JLabel` and I want to set both the height and width to a percentage of the `JFrame`, say 10%. How can this be achieved in Java? I have the `JLabel` named look and the `JFrame` named screen

```
JFrame screen = new JFrame("Example");
```

....

```
JPanel lookReplyGUIPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
JLabel lookx = new JLabel("something");
c.gridx = x+1;
c.gridy = y+1;     
lookReplyGUIPanel.add(lookx,c);
```

Thanks! all help appreciated

Comment: Not sure I understand the point of having a single component occupy 10% of the screen. I find there are usually better solutions than trying to control something like that. If you can give a more complete requirement for all the components on the frame I'm sure we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: @camickr Its a bit difficult to explain the whole thing but basically theres some JLabels and JButtons across the screen. I want the combination of all to fill the whole screen. I dont want to set a number as I'm wanting everything to resize when the window changes size. So 1 JLabel may take up 10% of the width, another 40% and so on. Hope this makes sense

Comment: if you can't explain your requirement, I'm not sure how we can help. You should not be specifying percentages for components, but just let components grow/shrink with the space available. A text label would not grow, but a text area in a scroll pane might. Use a proper combination of layout manager to achieve your desired requirement, but hardcoding sizes/percentages is not the way to do it.

Comment: `c.weightx = 0.1` and `c.weighty = 0.1`.  You may also need `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH`.  This will only size the label based on the size of it's parent container directly...

Comment: @camickr I want the width of the JLabel to take up 10% of the screen, so if its resized it takes up the same proportion of the screen. Whereas if using width=10 (most definatley incorrect as Im unsure how) this sets it no matter what the screen size is. Percentages may not be what I'm looking for but it to take up a proportion of the screen, the same no matter what the size of the window is.

Comment: In what way does setting a viewable item like a `JLabel` to be NN% of the available space actually make any sense?  It should be sized according to the content, which will necessarily take up a specific size in pixels, not percent.

Comment: @AndrewThompson  I want so that the component resizes proportionally with the main window. If it were x pixels width, if the window grew/shrink it would stay constant and may not take up the whole window with all other components. If it were, like I was asking a percentage, then I thought it would grow/shrink with the window keeping it proportional to the current size of the window. So I want the component to take up the same proportion of the window no matter what size the window is

Comment: *"I want so that the component resizes proportionally with the main window."*  Oh FFS!  We don't need to hear 'what you want' for the bloody tenth time.  Try to listen to what I'm telling you.  Put aside what you 'want' and describe ***why*** the UI needs to change in this way.  It is likely it needs an entirely different approach, like a `JTable`..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Im just trying to explain it. All the components need to fill the entire window no matter what the size is. So the window is always full

Comment: What your looking for is a different Layout Manger. Mig Layout is exactly what you need (http://www.miglayout.com/), not only will it do what you need - which I can see the need unlike others - it will not size smaller than its content. Meaning text in a JLabel will still be visible if the user re-sizes the window to small.