# gridheight moves component on top of each other

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

I have a `JFrame` which consists mainly of a left and right side. The left has 2 components 1 above the other, and the right has 9, again 1 on top of each other. As the left has 2, I want 1 component to equal the same vertical space as 6 on the right. I am using the `gridBagConstraints` layout and have each `JPanel` positioned in the main `JFrame`. Everything  looks OK (apart from what I was just saying). To sort this problem I use `c.gridHeight = 6` on the JPanel on the left. However this then puts the 6 `JPanels` which are on the right ontop of each other, ignoring their formatting. How can I rectify this problem? Snipets of my code which still cause the same problem are:

```
void create()
{
    JFrame screen = new JFrame("Dungeon of Doom");
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    screen.setSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));

    screen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));

    //Add all JPanes to screen
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridheight = 6;

    screen.add(lookReply(), c);


    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridx = 1;
    screen.add(title(), c);

    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;
    screen.add(space(), c);



    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    screen.add(commands(), c);

            //...So on, same for others

}
```

A sample method - the JPanel - all methods have the same content just different titles and less/more buttons/labels

```
private JPanel title()
{       

    JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    titlePanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    titlePanel.setOpaque(true);


    JLabel title = new JLabel("DOD");
    titlePanel.add(title, c);


    return titlePanel;
}
```

I put a background on the JPanels just to help see where they are in the window

All help appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: A [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hope that helps/is what you need

Comment: In you last posting (http://stackoverflow.com/q/22820177/131872) you were asked to post a `SSCCE`. Apparently you still don't understand what a `SSCCE` is because you didn't post one in this question. So ,now in this posting you were asked to post a `MVCE` which is the same concept as a `SSCCE` except with a different explanation of what is required. You haven't posted either a `SSCCE` or a `MVCE`. Please explain how the code you posted is runnable? I give up!

Comment: @camickr I opened the link which MadProgrammer put in his comment and no where in there it says post it compiled, it just says minimal complete and verifiable. Which is true for the code I put!!

Comment: @camickr Also I asked you in that question how do I post it, you never replied!!

Comment: @pokeairguy, I agree the MVCE link is not very helpful (which is why I still use the older SSCCE link) but if you read them both  you should be able to put 2 + 2 together to understand what they are asking for. Also, the `runnable example...` comment should be a giveaway. I didn't understand your other question, you know how to post code so posting a SSCCE is the same.

Comment: A 'minimal **complete** verifiable example' of a run-time problem must ..run.  Since those code snippets do not even compile, they are not **complete** and therefore not a verifiable example of a run-time problem.  Note:  I have not even seen your earlier question that mentions SSCCE/MCVE but wrote the first and wrote the first draft of the second.  OTOH my earlier failure to explain the difference between a problem and a feature to you had me thinking the communication problem was yours, so I just gave up.  I would not blame @camickr for not responding to a comment.

Comment: @camickr this one didnt say anything about compiling so I presumed you didnt need to. They have different names and that usually means they are different things!! As for the other question how did you not understand what I asked???!! Its simple English, you must have anyway as you've now answered it.

Comment: @pokeairguy, I didn't not understand what you asked. I couldn't understand WHY you were asking it since you already knew the answer. Also, why did you ask this question. Apparently it is not that important to you since in the last 13 hours you have yet to post your SSCCE. Why are you wasting the time of the people who read this question, when you are not prepared to listen to the advice given. This is not the first question that you have abandoned when we have asked for additional information.

Comment: @Camickr I asked how do I put the compiled code in. I also asked do I just put it in the question. Needed a simple yes/no answer. The last question I sorted myself and posted the answer. And this one I have decided to do it an alternate way as no-one seemed to answer my question of how!

Comment: @pokeairguy, `I also asked do I just put it in the question.` why didn't you just do it? People visit the forum at different time intervals. Why would you wait for me to reply? The SSCCE is important for anybody reading the question, not just me. Most people don't read a question twice so you lose a potential answer from that person. That is why ALL the information should be included with the initial question for the best chance of an answer. I was referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793418/set-a-jlabel-to-a-percentage-of-the-window

Comment: @camickr I wasn't sure if that was right, so I asked. Do you do anything unsure whether its right or not? That question the SSCCE was never asked for. And at that point I had never heard of it.

Comment: @pokeairguy, `Do you do anything unsure whether its right or not?` - yes I try things and then learn from my mistakes. If you do it wrong, then someone will make a comment. In the same way you didn't post a SSCCE/MCVE with your question so multiple people have made comments. Or you can actually try to read/answer questions other people post in the forums to see how other people ask questions and what kind of information they include with a question. Generally people think "learning by example" applies to writing code, but it can also apply to using a forum or anything else.

Comment: @camickr I try and look at other answers before posting a question. If I can't find anything or it doesn't work, I then post. And for all the questions I've seen people write a short paragraph of what they need/the problem and put the code underneath. And that is what I do.